# Do i need to release UITouch objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I have a method such as this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    //Use to animate drag
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self colorDragedOver:currentLocation];

    [touch release];

}
```

Do I need to release either the UITouch or the CGPoint to prevent any leaks?

Thanks!

Comment: The [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) are simple and all-inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You never `alloc/init` or `copy` the touch so it is considered autoreleased.

`CGPoint` isn't an object or a reference so should never be released or autoreleased.